# Add row containing sum of repeated string number in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am interested in to know how many zeros ("0") I have on each column. How do I generate a row which contains the sum of the number of "0" and non-zeros on each column?

```
Name <- c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4","G5", "G6")
Obs1 <- c(0, 1, 4, 7, 0, 2)
Obs2 <- c(6, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1)
Obs3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(Name, Obs1, Obs2, Obs3)
```

Desired output:

```
Name        Obs1    Obs2   Obs3

Zeros        2       2      5
Non-zeros    4       4      1
G1           0       6      0
G2           1       1      0
G3           4       0      0
G4           7       3      8
G5           0       0      0
G6           2       1      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colSums` to calculate zero and non-zero values in each column.

```
data <- data.frame(Name = c('Zero', 'Non-zero'), 
            rbind(colSums(df[-1] == 0), colSums(df[-1] != 0)))
rbind(data, df)  

#      Name Obs1 Obs2 Obs3
#1     Zero    2    2    5
#2 Non-zero    4    4    1
#3       G1    0    6    0
#4       G2    1    1    0
#5       G3    4    0    0
#6       G4    7    3    8
#7       G5    0    0    0
#8       G6    2    1    0
```

---

If you want a `dplyr` answer you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Obs'), list(Zero = ~sum(. == 0), 
                                            Nonzero = ~sum(. != 0)))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_sep = '_', 
               names_to = c('.value', 'Name')) %>%
  bind_rows(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R

```
df <- rbind(sapply(df, function(x) sum(x == 0)), sapply(df, function(x) sum(x != 0)),df)
df$Name[c(1,2)] <- c('Zero','Non-Zero')
df
      Name Obs1 Obs2 Obs3
1     Zero    2    2    5
2 Non-Zero    4    4    1
3       G1    0    6    0
4       G2    1    1    0
5       G3    4    0    0
6       G4    7    3    8
7       G5    0    0    0
8       G6    2    1    0
>
```